# при загрузке проверять какой input[type=radio] checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

задача стоит в том что есть два input[type=radio] и подкаждым блок к этому Input'у, если при клике на первый то под ним елемент станет видимым а другой елемент нет, если на второй то наоборот, проблема в том, что если при загрузке странице был checked второй инпут то мне нужно сделать проверку и показать значит второй блок, но почему событие не срабатывает
js:

```
this.regEventsRadio = function() {
        $('input[name=event_type]').change(function() {
            if (this.value === '1') {
                $('.js-multiple-event').addClass("active");
                $('.js-single-event').removeClass("active");
            }
            if (this.value === '2') {
                $('.js-single-event').addClass("active");
                $('.js-multiple-event').removeClass("active");
            }
        });
        $('input[name=event_type]:checked').trigger('click');
    };
```

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="event_type" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="event_type" value="2" checked>
<div class="js-single-event">single</div>
<div class="js-multiple-event">multiple</div>
```

Comment: вы бы это на стороне сервера лучше сделали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*trigger('**change**')*, а не *trigger('**click**')*

```
$('input[name=event_type]').change(function() {
   ...
});
$('input[name=event_type]:checked').trigger('change');
```